# Fetching large tables from Postgres into CSV using Python multiprocessing speed up

Tags: python, postgresql, multiprocessing, psycopg2, python-multiprocessing

I need to select all rows from several tables and save them in separate CSVs.

I am already using *multiprocessing.Pool* to make a separate process for each table.
But tables are quite large (2000000 rows each) and fetching all of them takes time.

```
 import psycopg2
 from multiprocessing import Pool

 def pg_to_csv(table_name):

     conn = psycopg2.connect(PG_DEV_CONFIG)
     cur = conn.cursor()

     query = f"""
         SELECT * FROM public.{table_name}
     """

     output_query = "COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(query)
     with open(table_name+'.csv', 'w') as output_csv:
         cur.copy_expert(output_query, output_csv)
         output_csv.close()

     conn.close()
     return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = ['table1', 'table2','table3','table4']
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(pg_to_csv, args)
```

What are the best practices at these kind of cases? How to speedup the process?

Comment: Is the database local, or on another host? [most of the time will be consumed by transferring data, so parellising wont win you any time]

Comment: @wildplasser It's remote. are you sure?

Comment: Unless your network connection has a larger bandwith than your disk I/O...

Comment: @wildplasser So there is no way to make reading from table parallel?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, your limitation is likely how fast individual resources are allocated to the process of downloading. My suggestion is to have four seperate scripts to be run from command line to download a single file. This will allow them to run independently and open up their own server connection independently.

Comment: Probably that's the question. How to download data from 1 table and save to 1 CSV file in multiple process es

Comment: **Why** do you want *multiple processes* ?